# Excel Formula. To generate random numbers based on an array of numbers and with a condition =Randomarray

Tags: arrays, excel, random, excel-formula, generator

Background: I have clients who get drug tested. They need to get drug tested 2x per a 7 day week. however, I don't want them finding out the pattern. So i want the pattern of numbers to change per every week. if someone gets tested monday and wednesday, then the following week they should get tested wednesday and friday.

Excel: As a result in excel I have an array of numbers lets say 1 through 65, to represent the patients. I have a formula that generates random numbers based on the array, for 10 columns. The data is present in 10 columns and 7 rows (sunday through sat (1 week)). Formula here: =RANDARRAY(A2:J8,10,1,65,TRUE). However I need each number / patient to get repeated / tested 2x per every week.  I got the formula to generate 7 random numbers per day, based on the array. But what I don't know how to do is make sure the numbers are randomly generated every week with a different pattern.

Also there can't be any repeating numbers in any one day.

Let me know if this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Try this function out, just copy and paste:

=LET(c,SEQUENCE(65),VSTACK({"Patient Number","Test Days"},HSTACK(c,MAP(c,LAMBDA(p,TEXTJOIN(", ",,TAKE(SORTBY({"Sun";"Mon";"Tue";"Wed";"Thu";"Fri";"Sat"},RANDARRAY(7)),2)))))))